# OpenGL ES 2.0 stride performance

Tags: opengl-es

Does the size of the struct (containing the vertex data) affect the performance in anyway?

Example:

```
struct VertexData1 {
     float x, y, z;
}

struct VertexData1 {
     float x, y, z;
     float variable1, variable2; //any amount of variables
}
```

now, would there be any performance difference between:

```
struct VertexData1 d1;
glVertexAttribPointer(index, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData1), &d1.x);
```

vs

```
struct VertexData2 d2;
glVertexAttribPointer(index, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct VertexData2), &d2.x);
```

?

Comment: It affects how much memory that takes. But that's typically fine. For optimizing OpenGL, it is recommended that you have an array that has a bunch of your attributes, load it into video memory once, and then re-use the array (i.e. use a specific attribute of the array by setting the stride so other attributes are skipped). That's faster loading several arrays into video memory.

Comment: There could be a difference. It's not only the amount of memory you use, as @Cornstalks pointed out, but also how much memory is read, and correspondingly how many cache misses you get during vertex fetching. Say the vertex fetcher uses a cache line size of 64 bytes. In your first example, where the data is packed at 12 bytes per vertex, you would read 5+ vertices at the price of a single cache miss. If there's unused padding in the data, you could end up with more cache misses, and more memory reading. This should rarely be a bottleneck, but it does potentially add overhead.

Comment: My intention was to use extra variables in the structs, which will go unused (unused padding). Looks like i can't now. @Cornstalks and Reto Koradi, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because it'll affect overall locality of succeeding references (ie, they'll get less local) and therefore will increase your number of cache misses, especially as the number of vertices goes up.

In your case you're not storing the array on the GPU but if you're interested in performance, you should be. OpenGL can't automatically cache this stuff because there's no bookkeeping in C that would allow it to tell whether anything within the array has changed since the previous call to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Arranging yourself for good caching once you're pushing to the GPU becomes even more important: GPUs are highly parallel but memory isn't. So cache misses all fall back on a shared resource and hence multiple simultaneous misses compound performance problems.

So what you generally want is to fit every piece of data relevant to a vertex together into one block (position, normal, tangent, all texture coordinates, specularity, etc, etc) with each stored in the absolute lowest precision container you can get away with. If you work with really small GPUs like those usually used for OpenGL ES it is also often cheaper to leave as much implicit as possible and to recalculate it — e.g. store a two-component normal and work out the third in the shader based on the constraint that normals are stored as unit length in 99.9999% of all engines.

Comment: Low precision containers like struct of floats instead of double?

Comment: Yes, or even smaller — e.g. `GL[u]byte` is standard for colour and normal components. That's largely what the normalise flag, just before you specify the stride, is there for.